# Using getchar() in a while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, getchar

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int c ;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        int isEOF = (c==EOF);
        printf("is %c EOF: %d ", c, isEOF);
    }
}
```

Why printf() method is called twice on every input char here?

If i give a input 'a', I am getting the result like

```
E:\C_workouts>gcc CharIO.c -o CharIO.exe

E:\C_workouts>CharIO.exe
a
is a EOF: 0 is
 EOF: 0
```

The same happens on every input.

Answer (score 2):

#### Because you typed '`a`' *and* '`\n`'...

The '`\n`' is a result of pressing the `[ENTER]` key after typing into your terminal/console's input line.  The `getchar()` function will return each character, one at a time, until the input buffer is clear.  So your loop will continue to cycle until `getchar()` has eaten any remaining characters from the `stdin` stream buffer.

If you are expecting the `stdin` input buffer to be clear when calling `getchar()` then you should ***flush `stdin`*** with `while((ch=getchar())!='\n'&&ch!=EOF);` to consume any previous contents in the buffer just before calling `getchar()`.  Some implementations (ie. many DOS/Windows compilers) offer a non-standard `fflush(stdin);`

Answer (score 1):

Because in some implementations of getchar() when you press the key 'x' and ENTER, there are two caracters in the buffer (the 'x' and a newline char). (I know, this is a little dumb)
You should skip  newlines in your loop.

Update: this was already answered here: [Where does `getchar()` store the user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004314/getchar-question)

Comment: It's subjective... but I don't think that the implementation behaves as one would expect, and tons of programmers (myself included) have been bitten by this. Judging from the man page ("reads the next character from stream") we would expect that each key is read as soon as it pressed; actually the stdin is buffered by lines. (which can besides be edited - i.e. a backspace wont be sent as a key, etc)
http://c-faq.com/osdep/cbreak.html
And even when one learns about this behaviour, is not obvious at all that the ENTER key will produce a newline character.

Answer (score -2):

This should work...

```
    int c ;
    while (((c=getchar())^EOF)) 
        printf("is %c EOF: %d ", c, c^EOF?0:1);
```

Comment: XOR with EOF is unnecessarily ugly. Also, your code still has the same behaviour as the OP's.