# why does getchar in while not execute after first iteration?

Tags: c

I wrote a program to read from input character by character and print it to output and here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{

    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%s\n", "log1");
        printf("%c\n", c);
        printf("%s\n", "log2");
    }

}
```

and this is the result:

```
a(my input)
log1
a
log2
log1


log2
```

but it should have this result:

```
a
log1
a
log2
```

what's wrong with this program?

Comment: Did you try looking to several hundred related answers on SO, before clicking the "Post Your Question" Button ?

Comment: Are you sure, you don't type in anything else but the character 'a' ?

Comment: Guess you entered before being told not to do so. Bad boy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you giving input a and newline

```
a(my input)  You are giving a and newline

//this is because of a 
log1
a
log2 

//this is because of newline
log1


log2
```

Check for newline and avoid printing Newline.

```
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        {
            if(c!='\n')
               {  
                printf("%s\n", "log1");
                printf("%c\n", c);
                printf("%s\n", "log2");
               }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you `while((c = getchar()) != EOF)` ends after hitting EOF. This is because when you type something and you hit the enter key then everything is stored in an internal buffer.

Your code stops when `getchar` doesn't find anything in that buffer.

You may also check out this:- **[Where does `getchar()` store the user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004314/where-does-getchar-store-the-user-input)**

Comment: Try pressing Ctrl + D after some input.

Answer (score 0):

`getchar` is running during the second iteration. The problem is that your input was actually "a[enter]", so the second character that `getchar` read was a newline character, and it printed that.

If you give input of "abc", the things may seem more clear.

Answer (score 0):

while(getchar() != '\n');

bear in mind that the expression in the while loop is executed everytime - so even when the character is '\n' is found, it has already been removed from the stream by the getchar() call.

Answer (score 0):

Place a condition not to print `\n` (on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
  while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        {
            if(c != '\n') 
            printf("%s\n", "log1");
            printf("%c\n", c);
            printf("%s\n", "log2");
        }
```