# Learning C, looping error

Tags: c

I have been tasked to create a simple lower to upper case program. However, while testing if my input prints correctly, I have noticed that every time I enter a character, it always loops again even when its not supposed to.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char input;

  //enter a character
  //set the given input char to variable
  printf("Enter a character in lower case: \n");
  input = getchar();

  //Sentinel value is Q
  while (input != 'Q'){
    printf("you entered %c.\n",input);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Enter a character in lower case: \n");
    input = getchar();  //gets input from inside the loop
  }
  printf("Goodbye \n");
  return 0;
}
```

test output (I input the character 'g' and pressed enter once):

```
Enter a character in lower case:
g
you entered g.

Enter a character in lower case:
you entered
.
```

I'm not seeing the problem.

Comment: Have you tried entering `Q` and seeing what happens?

Comment: It's printing the `'\n'` (newline) character.

Comment: There are many dups of this which you may find relevant: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549701/using-getchar-in-a-while-loop 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342434/why-does-getchar-in-while-not-execute-after-first-iteration?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is caused by the `newline` character entred into the `stdin` by pressing the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key. Before proceeding for the next input, you need to clear the input buffer , like adding

```
 while (getchar() != '\n');
```

before asking for the next input.

That said, [`getchar()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) returns an `int`. A `char` may not be enough to hold the return value always, Change

```
 char input;
```

to

```
int input = 0;
```